# Alternative (old) meaning of shoes

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

This quote from Lud-in-the-Mist by Hope Mirrlees is clearly (from the context) not about shoes:

> This fear, too, had awakened in him a wistful craving for other men's shoes that caused him to take a passionate interest in the lives of his neighbors; that is to say if these lives moved in a different sphere from his own.

It seems to mean something like 'worries' - are there anyone here who knows the precise meaning?

Comment: Are you familiar with the proverb *[don't judge a man till you have walked a mile in his shoes](https://books.google.com/books?id=LPZfi4ADcusC&pg=PA166&lpg=PA166#v=onepage&q&f=false)*?

Comment: Or the Groucho Marks joke, "*Before you insult a man, walk a mile in his shoes...That way, when you insult him, you'll be a mile away and you'll have his shoes.*"

Comment: I don't think this is about the 'mile in his shoes'-proverb, it seems here like a seperate word (this was written ca. 1925, by the way)

Comment: Can you provide more context, then? It seems to me he has a craving to live as someone other than himself, the shoes being a metaphor whose meaning is understood via the proverb.

Comment: "Put yourself in his shoes" and similar metaphors are well-established.  The subject sentence appears to be referring to such a metaphor, only perhaps in a backwards fashion, to imply that envy rather than sympathy results.

Comment: @HotLicks I agree that the more usual implication is a negative one - *I'm glad I'm not in his shoes*!

Comment: To use a metaphor is not unusual, but it is used in an unusual way: '...craving for other men's shoes...'. Later she writes: 'He even coveted dead men's shoes'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fear, too, had awakened in him a wistful craving for other men's shoes that caused him to take a passionate interest in the lives of his neighbors

"shoes" in this context means **"positions"** or **"situations"**

> - **shoes : another person's situation or position** -  [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shoe)

Perhaps something in his life made him wish he were somebody else, and the result was that he took a passionate interest in the lives of his neighbours.

Comment: And then it is in fact metaphorical, as @choster kind of suggested?

Comment: @Stefan It surely is.

Comment: @Josh61 I've deleted it. Sorry if that caused any sort of embarassment.